# SwiftUI:how to get the secondView showed in full screen when I transfer to secondView from firstView

Tags: swiftui

SwiftUI:
I am trying to transfer to secondView from firstView on iPad Pro(11inch) Horizontal screen,the secondView can not be showed in full screen
here is my code:

```js
    import SwiftUI
 
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showsecondView: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
   
        Button(action: {
            self.showsecondView.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("firstView")
        }.sheet(isPresented: self.$showsecondView){
            secondView(showsecondView: self.$showsecondView)
        }
    
    }
}
 
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
struct secondView: View {
    @Binding var showsecondView: Bool
    var body: some View {
   
       Text("secondView")
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsytX.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no SwiftUI Feature to present Modal Views Full Screen.

If you do not need the swipe to dismiss feature in the second view, have a look at 
the following video:

[Brian Voong - Fullscreen Modal Animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=514A7yzznJE&t=633s)

This  is a hack with combining two ZStacks. In the second ZStack you can implement yout second View